# Magento: get gender and birthday from order (user is not logged in)

Tags: magento

I was trying to retrieve gender from order like this (user ist not logged in):

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

$gender = $order->getBillingAddress()->getGender();
```

but it does not work :( I was searching on google for some help but found nothing helpfull. Does anyone knows how to retrieve the gender and also the birthday?

Thank you!

#### UPDATE

I want to get the gender and birthday for a guest order - the gender and birthday fields are in the checkout form

#### SOLVED!

There was a silly problem with my Firefox - customer_dob and customer_gender was not saved into the DB :(

For those who want's to see the solution - this data are stored in sales_flat_order table (customer_dob and customer_gender).

So you can get both attributes with:

```
$order->getCustomerDob();
$order->getCustomerGender();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the customer from the order.

`$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());`

You then can print the customer data to see the available data and how to fetch the gender and birthday. I don't know it from memory.

`print_r($customer->getData());`

Birthday must be something like
`$customer->getDob();`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but the $order->getCustomerId() is NULL because the customer is not logged in. That's the problem :)

Is the gender and birthday maybe stored in billingAddress object or elsewhere?

Comment: The customer does not need to be logged in for you to get the customer data from the order. If you look at the Magento database into the table sales_flat_order you can see the field "customer_id". With the above code you can load the corresponding customer data for each order. I do not know why your order has no customer_id. How was the order created?  Or did you delete the customer who initially placed the order?

Comment: ok, my mistake... there will be no customer_id saved for guest orders in the database. So is there a possibility to get the gender for a guest order? Sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: the gender and birthday is in the checkout form

Comment: Ah, alright. Unfortunately, I don't know how these values are saved for the guest user and if this is possible in default Magento at all. But you can try $order->getCustomerDob() for the birthday. As for the gender: You could use $order->getCustomerPrefix() which returns Mr and Mrs and return the values male and female accordingly. I hope you're getting a result with that.

Comment: Thank you! $order->getCustomerDob() works as well as $order->getCustomerGender() - there was a silly problem with my firefox - the data was not written into the DB, in anonymous window was everything fine and all the data was saved in sales_flat_order table - perfect! Many thanks!!!